# A committee of $6$ is chosen from $8$ men and $5$ women so as to contain at least $2$ men and $3$ women.

Tags: permutations, combinations

A committee of $6$ is chosen from $8$ men and $5$ women so as to contain at least $2$ men and $3$ women. How many different committees could be formed if two of the men refuse to serve together?

($1$) $635$

($2$) $700$

($3$) $1404$

($4$) $2620$

($5$) $3510$

Comment: Did you change the statement of the question after it was answered?  If so, in fairness to Aniket, you should restate the original question.  If you have a new question, you should pose it as a separate question in which you explain your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer will involve combinations only and is equal to $(^8_7)(^{10}_0)+(^8_6)(^{10}_1)+(^8_5)(^{10}_2)+(^8_4)(^{10}_3)+(^8_3)(^{10}_4)=?$ Calculate the answer.

Comment: Thanks Aniket, You make it look so simple :)

Comment: You're welcome...If you like my answer, you can click the green tick on the left side and accept my answer.

Comment: i was doing only last part. At most 4 means i need to add all possible combinations.. is that so...?

Comment: What do you mean by " 
i was doing only last part. At most 4 means i need to add all possible combinations"? At most 4 means the committee can have at maximum 4 women, i.e. 0,1,2,3,4 women ...these are the combinations.

Comment: My way of thinking about this is that the last combination ll do work...

Comment: Why do you say so? What is your logic behind this?